# Present letter occurrences as asterisks above each letter in alphabet

Tags: php, arrays

I have a code that will count the frequency of an alphabet in a string. . My code is :

```
<?php
    $str = "iamtheone";
    $freq_count = array();
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $index = $str[$i];
        $freq_count[$index]++;
    
        foreach (range('a', 'z') as $char) {
            //echo "<pre>".$key . " " . $char."</pre>";
            $index = $char;
            if (isset($freq_count[$index])) {
            } else {
                $freq_count[$index] = "0";
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($freq_count);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [i] => 1
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 0
    [c] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [e] => 2
    [f] => 0
    [g] => 0
    [h] => 1
    [j] => 0
    [k] => 0
    [l] => 0
    [m] => 1
    [n] => 1
    [o] => 1
    [p] => 0
    [q] => 0
    [r] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [t] => 1
    [u] => 0
    [v] => 0
    [w] => 0
    [x] => 0
    [y] => 0
    [z] => 0
)
```

Now I want them to convert the array in this following format:

```
         *
 *       *     * *       * * *         *
 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

Explanation: The number of asterisks will be depends on how many is the frequency of each alphabet. For example, the `a` is only one time repeat in the string , the `e` is two times repeated in the string and so on.

Is my array format correct?

Comment: You can simplify all your existing code to `$str ="iamtheone";

$freq_count = array_merge(
    array_fill_keys(range('a', 'z'), 0),
    array_count_values(str_split($str))
);
 
var_dump($freq_count);` which has the added advantage of already being sorted by character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your teacher won't believe you did this without help, but:

```
$str ="iamtheone";

// Calculate the frequency table for all letters
$letters = array_fill_keys(range('a', 'z'), ' ');
$freq_count = array_merge(
    $letters,
    array_count_values(str_split(strtolower($str)))
);

// Plot the display chart
for ($line = max($freq_count); $line > 0; --$line) {
    echo implode(
        ' ', 
        array_map(
            function ($value) use ($line) {
                return ($value >= $line) ? '*' : ' ';
            },
            $freq_count
        )
    );
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
echo implode(' ', array_keys($lineArray)), PHP_EOL;
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Gch04G)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it, just add an asterisk to each discovered char, no need to count the number of occurrences as a number - also could use strtolower() to convert upper case chars and count them as well:

```
$freqCount = array();
$countedStr = 'iamtheone';

// inits the frequency count array
foreach (range('a','z') as $char) {
    $freqCount[$char] = '';
}

for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++) {
    $index = $countedStr[$i]; 
    // potentially convert to lower case: 
    //  $index = strtolower($countedStr[$i]); 
    $freqCount[$index] .= '*'; // adds an asterisk to the letter
}
```